# Boolean model containing both confusion and junk

Tags: model-theory, boolean-algebra

I'm doing a course in Equational Programming, and really new to these materials.

So we got a specification for Booleans:

```
spec Booleans
    sorts bool
    functions:
        true : -> bool
        false : -> bool
        and : bool # bool -> bool
        or : bool # bool -> bool
        not : bool -> bool
    equations:
        [B1] and(true,x) = x
        [B2] and(false,x) = false
        [B3] not(true) = false
        [B4] not(false) = true
        [B5] or(x,y) = not(and(not(x),not(y)))
end Booleans
```

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a model for specification $((S, \Sigma), E)$, $\mathfrak{A}$ contains
junk if $\mathfrak{A}$ contains elements that are not the interpretation of a closed term. A contains confusion if $\mathfrak{A}$ identifies two closed terms t and u, without t = u being derivable from E. Or formally:

"no junk": $\forall a \in A \; s.t. \exists t \in {Ter}_\Sigma \; s.t. \; {eval}_{\mathfrak{A}}(t) \equiv a$

"no confusion" : $\forall t, u \in {Ter}_{\Sigma}({eval}_{\mathfrak{A}}(t) \equiv {eval}_{\mathfrak{A}}(u)) \Rightarrow E \vdash t = u$

Now one of the questions was to give a model for the specification booleans s.t.  it would have both **confusion** and **junk** (in the same model)

The TA didn't think it possible but couldn't prove it. I've done some googling afterwards and found the book *Foundations of Algebraic Specification and Formal Software Development*, I couldn't entirely read it (only parts are available online, I'm not rich enough to buy on good faith), apparently in section 2.5.3  (page 57) they claim their spec does have a model containing both junk and confusion.

I simply already don't understand what such a model would be like (containing both confusion and junk), let alone construct a model for the spec above.

With the spec above, is a model with both confusion and junk possible, if not why not?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Edit: added definitions of confusion and junk for future reference.

Comment: I think this Q belongs on StackExchange or StackOverflow which are  about programming.

Comment: I dont think it's about programming though as it's more theoretical cs. I wouldn't know what other stackexchange i should post this on otherwise.

Comment: Apparently confusion and junk are being used in some technical sense here... Could you explain it or give a reference?

Comment: Googling found the following definitions of "confusion" and "junk": https://helios.hud.ac.uk/scomtlm/book/node280.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no model with both junk and confusion, assuming I am interpreting those words correctly (I am using the definitions given [here](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/scomtlm/book/node280.html)).  First note that it is easy to deduce from the given equational axioms that every term with no variables must be equal to either $\mathtt{true}$ or $\mathtt{false}$ (B1-B4 tell you how to evaluate $\mathtt{not}$ and $\mathtt{and}$, and then B5 reduces evaluting $\mathtt{or}$ to $\mathtt{not}$ and $\mathtt{and}$).  So the only way you can have confusion in a model is if $\mathtt{true}=\mathtt{false}$.  But in that case, axioms B1 and B2 together tell you that for any $x$, $x=\mathtt{and}(\mathtt{true},x)=\mathtt{and}(\mathtt{false},x)=\mathtt{false}$.  So in any model with confusion, every element is equal to $\mathtt{false}$, so there is no junk.

(In the language of abstract algebra that is probably more familiar to most readers here, what we are proving here is that if $B$ is a Boolean algebra such that the map from the initial Boolean algebra to $B$ is not injective, then the map from the initial Boolean algebra to $B$ is surjective.  This is just because the only way it can fail to be injective is if $0=1$ in $B$, which can only happen in the trivial Boolean algebra.)